# linq to sql - Is Entity.Where().Single() better than Entity.Single()

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am using Linq to Sql. I have table names customer and I want to fetch a single record.
I have following two options:

```
1. datacontext.Customer.Where( a => a.CustId == 1).Single();

2. datacontext.Customer.Single(a => a.CustId == 1)
```

which option is better one from performance point and why?

Tell the internals working of both these options.

Comment: I think part of the idea of Linq is that you don't need to know the "internals". Fire up SQL Profiler and look at the queries as they run - my guess is that they'd be identical.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe (test results) it is different, as well as relevant to the overall performance of your application? If not I'd go for option 2, it expresses your intent the clearest.

Answer (score 1):

From a SQL query perspective, 1 results in

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Naam] FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [t0] WHERE [t0].[Id] = @p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=1
```

and 2 results in

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Naam] FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [t0] WHERE [t0].[Id] = @p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=1
```

Which are exactly the same. So there are no performance differences there. I don't have insight on the LINQ to SQL query builder, so I don't know which one is faster from that perspective, but I doubt it's significant (I would say only 2 is better because it simply saves you a method call and the corresponding entries in the query object).